# Can anyone explain these dips in the early 2000s coffee commodity market?

Tags: trading, commodities

### Please explain these dips

In the early 2000s coffee commodity experienced sudden massive short term dips that crashed prices into negative territory from highs of $50 to $100 each time.

**Can someone please explain what causes this phenomenon?**

**Have safeguards against these kinds of drops been implemented so that it won't happen again?**

---

[image: sudden price drops 2001 to 2010]

I have tried to google explanations for this but cannot find results. Possibly it's because I do not know what the technical phrase is for describing events like these is

Thank you

[image: Massive drops in the early 2000s]

Comment: This is just data errors - the database doesn't have a value, so it draws 0. No connection to reality.

Comment: I see that makes sense. But will there be a risk of a margin call from these errors?

Comment: Nope. Actually they indicate some person on the data maintenance side that is not smart enoug hto validate data. See, this prints are outside the order book, and likely have some other warnings and thus should be filtered out.